# GROUP BY SQL statement Error

Tags: sql, group-by, derby

I got this statement

```
SELECT ITEM.ITEMID, ITEMNAME, QUANTITY AS "QUANTITY SOLD" 
FROM ORDERITEM,
     NBUSER."ORDER",
     PAYMENT,
     ITEM
WHERE NBUSER."ORDER".PAYMENTID = PAYMENT.PAYMENTID
  AND ITEM.ITEMID = ORDERITEM.ITEMID
  AND PAYMENT.PAYMENTDATE BETWEEN '4/1/2017' AND '4/30/2017' 
GROUP BY ITEM.ITEMID
ORDER BY ITEM.ITEMID DESC;
```

But it keeps giving me this error:

> [Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42Y36] Column reference
>   'ITEM.ITEMNAME' is invalid, or is part of an invalid expression.  For
>   a SELECT list with a GROUP BY, the columns and expressions being
>   selected may only contain valid grouping expressions and valid
>   aggregate expressions. Line 1, column 1

I want to join the records with similar itemid together and adding the quantity up for all the same itemid.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Error is self explained read it. You should include the select list columns into the group by clause or use aggregate functions.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit JOIN syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are used? Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text!

Comment: Another tip: Use table aliases to save some typing and make the query easier to read.

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. The reason it doesn't work is very simple: `GROUP BY` creates groups of records, all records in each group having the same value of `ITEM.ITEMID`. Then, from each group, `SELECT` tries to **create** a row and put it into the result set. It's easy to select a value for the `ITEM.ITEMID` expression because all the rows in the group have the same value of this column. Most probably they also have the same value of `ITEMNAME`. But the expression `QUANTITY` is indeterminate. The rows from the group have different values in this column. Which one to pick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First of all, you have 4 tables in the statement, but only 2 joins. 
   Do you do this intentionally? If not, you need to specify 1 more join.
2. When you use group by only for a part of columns in select, you must have an aggregate function for remaining columns in the select clause, in your case, for example:

---

```
select ITEM.ITEMID, max(ITEMNAME), sum(QUANTITY) AS "QUANTITY SOLD" ...
```

3. It is better to use table aliases for each column, otherwise, it is difficult to understand the sql statement in general.
   You have defined alias here - `ITEM.ITEMID` (`ITEM` is an alias), but not there -  `ITEMNAME`.

Answer (score 1):

For the future reader, who may use another DBMS:
Depending on the standard version and the vendor, it may be allowed to additionally use columns in the SELECT statement, which are only functionally dependent on the grouping columns.

Source: An SQL 2008 standard draft ([Link](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql200n.zip)), part II, 7.12  -> General rule number 15:

" If T is a grouped table, then let G be the set of grouping columns of T. In each `<value expression>` contained
in `<select list>` , each column reference that references a column of T shall reference some column C that
is functionally dependent on G or shall be contained in an aggregated argument of a  whose aggregation query is QS.
"